# How do I replicate the Get comand used by IntelliJ Idea to go back to earlier git commit but keep ion master branch not go in detached state

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I use git in a simple way that works usually well for me. I am sole developer and I just use a single master branch, working on one fix/feature at a time I commit regularly (a few times a day) to my master branch and once a day I push back to the remote master branch hosted on bitbucket.

Occasionally I want to go back a few steps and using my IDE (Intelli Jetbrains) I can use *Get* to go back to a previous commit and then in carry on and commit further changes to master without problems.

But I dont know what *Get* does under the covers as this does not seem to be a Git command.

Can someone tell me the correct set of commands to  replicate this from command line. So that I can go back to earlier commit whilst staying on the master branch and then a subsequent commit will mean the codebase is same as this earlier commit plus changes in the commit.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the actual _Get_ command/button that you're using (I couldn't find it)? WIth that information, it should be possible to find out what exactly  happens behind the scenes by checking the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community).

Answer (score 1):

The detached state is caused by your having said `git checkout` or `git switch` with the SHA of the commit you want to go back to. Instead, use `git reset --hard`. You could say simply

```
get reset --hard <SHA>
```

Alternatively, you can do this by counting steps:

```
git reset --hard @~<n>
```

where *`<n>`* is the number of steps (commits) back you want to go. For example, if you have

```
A -- B -- C -- D <- master
```

then

```
git reset --hard @~2
```

will give you

```
A -- B <- master
```

and now you are ready to make new commits on `master` starting after B.

Observe that this throws away commits C and D. If you think there might be some reason for preserving them, make a branch *before* the hard reset, like this:

```
git branch maybe-useful-so-keep-it
```

(or whatever branch name you'd like to use here).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go back to B without losing C and D, Essentially, I think I want a new commit after D called E which is identical code wise to B

the way to do it without removing the other commits it to use `git reset --soft <sha>`  this will reset the HEAD to commit `B`, then you can make other commits and and any changes from `C` and `D` will be included in the next commit you perform.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---soft

you can also view the `console` tab in your IDE to view the commands executed by the git client.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html